# Google+ API Email Scope

Tags: php, google-plus

According to the google+ [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth) there is only one scope which is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me , but this scope does not contain email address of the user. how to get the email of the user with google+ API

Comment: may be google+ API does not support request for user email address ??

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the email address of the user you have to add the following scope to your access request: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`